# Handling Data in long format in R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, mean

I created a data frame in longformat which has 5 variables( company name, key item, country of origin, year and value) What I want to do is create a table with the means of the values of one key item for each year. Here is what I managed so far:

```
for(i in dat$Year) {
  dat[dat$KeyItem == "Total Assets" & dat$Year == i, ]
  FUN1 <- mean(dat$Value, na.rm = TRUE)


}
```

I have hardly any experience in R and I am sorry if this question is too easy.
Thank you guys in advance for your help.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: It sounds like you want a function like `aggregate()`, but as @PaulHiemstra mentions, it's hard to say without at least some sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not share your data, it is a little hard to judge what you want exactly. Probably, you want to use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
mean_values = ddply(dat, .(key_item, year), summarise, mn_value = mean(Value))
```

If your dataset becomes really big, you might opt to teach yourself the `data.table` package which is blisteringly fast in these cases. For medium sized datsets, `ddply` might also be slower, but is fast enough.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what i wanted :)

Comment: If this answered your question, it is customary to click on the green tick mark, and/or press the upvote button.